# How to get master page control in content page's update panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Have a label control in master page.Should get this control to content page's update panel.
The code in content page is

```
ModalPopupExtender popUp = (ModalPopupExtender)Master.FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1");
HtmlGenericControl lblMessage = (HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("InfoMesg");

lblMessage.InnerText = "Invalid page number, Please enter valid page number.";
popUp.Show();
```

When update panel is place the message in lblMessage is not being displayed.
Can someone please help me achieve this.

Comment: When postback is triggered by UpdatePanel (so to say), the only part of the page that will be updated on response is the UpdatePanel content. This label is outside of the UpdatePanel, therefore it won't be updated.

Comment: yes , what u told is correct. But i want to solve this problem another way. Mentioning the updatepanel in master page using triggers to that updatepanel.

Comment: Gathered couple of ideas in an answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why isn't it working? When postback is triggered by `UpdatePanel` (so to say), the only part of the page that will be updated on response is the `UpdatePanel` content. This label is outside of the UpdatePanel; therefore it won't be updated.

How to work around this anyway:

1. Obvious, but in theory most welcome solution. Move label inside the `UpdatePanel`, if it is something that logically belongs there. Of course this might not apply to your particular case.
2. `UpdatePanel` could register some script that would update the text of the label (make sure to use `ClientID`).
3. If your `UpdatePanel` does not have an `UpdateMode` set, or it is set to `Always` (basically this is a default value), afaik all other update panels will be updated as well when this one causes a postback. So you can wrap the label in a separate `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: I have a label inside a UpdatePanel in master page and I am trying to trigger an event from a button in my content page to update the update panel but for some reason it is not working. Please help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513337/update-masterpage-control-from-content-page